# User Defined type not defined

Tags: excel, vba

I continue to get a user-defined error.   This code is very helpful in exporting data to access.   It just won't kick off because of the User-defined error.

Thank you

```
    Public Sub AccImport()

    Dim acc As DAO.Database
    acc.OpenCurrentDatabase "C:\Users\public\Database1.accdb"
    acc.DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet _
        acImport, _
        acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, _
        "tblExcelImport", _
        Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName, _
        True, _
        "Folio_Data_original$A1:B10"
    acc.CloseCurrentDatabase
    acc.Quit
    Set acc = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to **Set** *acc* in your code??

Comment: I agree with Gary and Andy, and also the name of your `Range` is missing a `!` in `"Folio_Data_original$A1:B10"`. I believe Andy spotted the error you get, but as soon as you correct it Gary's observation and then mine will come into play (in this order).

Answer (score 2):

You should tell us which line the error refers to, but it is most likely the second.

You need to add a reference to the DAO library. Go to Tools, References and find and tick Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library, so that you can then use `DAO.` in your code.

But `OpenCurrentDatabase` is an Access method. To use this, and then call TransferSpreadsheet, you need to use Access Automation. This involves:

- Having a Reference to the Access Object Library
- Creating a new instance of the Access Application, and having an
  object variable that refers to this new instance

Then you can use `OpenCurrentDatabase` and `TransferSpreadsheet`.

Comment: I believe, however, that it can be problematic to run a Macro Action from Access that uses the currently open Excel Workbook. (Better to run the code from a different Workbook.) I don't have recent experience of this though, so I may be over-stating it.